# return value based on selection

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am trying to return a specific value in page item 2 based on  what is selected in page item 1 using a dynamic action from page item 1.

So for example

when detailspec (which is my page item 1) is 'N/A' then specificationscore (which is my page item 2) should display '0'

Or When detailspec (which is my page item 1) is 'Surpass' then specificationscore (which is my page item 2) should display '1'

Below is an example of what i think i should use but i  am not sure

```
eg. 

declare 
....
If detailspec(pageitem1) = N/A
        then return value =0 (in :p5_SPECIFICATIONSCORE(pageitem2)
    elseif
         detailspec(pageitem1) = surpass
         then return value =1 (in :p5_SPECIFICATIONSCORE(pageitem2)
```

Comment: Is this for APEX?

Comment: Please edit your question to add your page item names, some example values, and what you expect the values to be afterwards. Are you trying to do this in an item source, page process, or calculation?

Comment: I agree with kfinity, we need more info to help. Please answer those questions.

Comment: my apologies let me add some more information also the page item is detailspec and specificationscore that why i had spage item next to them so you will know which is page item 1 and page item 2

Answer (score 0):

This may help. The mytest could hold the value returned from your function and rather than display the value, just return it as you appear to be attempting.

```
declare
  value number;
  mytest varchar2(20);
begin
  mytest := 'what';

  case mytest
    when 'N/A' then value := 0;
    when 'surpass' then value := 1;
    else value := 2;
  end case;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('value=' || value);
end;
/
```